# fix gnome-terminal for a user

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

`gnome-terminal` will not start for a user, but will start for `root` or other users. What can I reset or delete to get it back to initial state? I tried reinstalling `gnome-terminal` it did not help. Then I uninstalled all apps related to Gnome i.e. having gnome in their name or description, then installed gnome-terminal again, but it did not help. Also I deleted various config files in the home dir, to no avail. Then I used dconf to reset some settings but it also did not help, although I must admit I am not sure I understood how dconf works, there is no delete button anywhere.

I also googled anything related to gnome-terminal errors on startup, tried various suggestions from there related to DBus and something else, do not remember everything, this problem persists for almost a year for me, I even wanted to delete my user and create the new one, but that's an unwanted overkill of course.

Answer (score 2):

I often see this kind of problems when the configuration of a program does not match the version installed. In this case you must clear the old configuration or regenerate it someway.

As you know, `gnome-terminal` stores its configuration using `GSettings` (that by default uses the `dconf` backend), resulting in data stored into the `$HOME/.config/dconf/user` binary file. If you do not mind losing **all** your GNOME settings (ALL of them), I would try to rename it using your `root` account (it is not sane to rename a file while using it, so you should not touch it while logged in as the problematic user). The problem could also be triggered by other temporary files though, stored e.g. into `$HOME/.local` or `$HOME/.cache`.

It would help a lot to have some debugging info. You can run the following command in another terminal (e.g. `xterm`) just to see what happens:

```
G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all gnome-terminal
```